# How to optimize includes and forward declarations in a Qt project and when do i need <QtGui> and <Qt>

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a UI with Qt and do a lot of subclassing of given Qt objects. While doing so, regarding the including of modules and header files, i tried to stick to examples from the Qt reference. Now, refactoring all my code, i decided to stick to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) approach: `A` makes no reference to `B`: do nothing. If `A` contains `B*` or `B&` or either of those appear as return type or parameter: forward declare. If `B` is a parent of `A` or if `A` contains a `B` object: `B myB;`: include `B`'s header.

Doing this raised a question, since i often see that `<Qt>` and `<QtGui>` are included (for example [here](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QLed+?content=72482)) when neither of them seem to be of use to me. The detailed description in the [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtgui-module.html#details) also does not enlight me. So my question is:

***When do i need to include those and when do i not to include those modules?***

Also i ask my self if it is a good idea to stick to the above approach very strictly. It seems legit to me.

Comment: I agree with your approach. These modules have exactly the same rules as a normal C++ header file. In detailed reference document it explicits 'To include the definitions'.

Comment: Follow the motto of C++, "you don't pay for what you don't need". Only include what's necessary at a given place, and stay away from those fat headers that import every symbol ever, polluting you local space.

Comment: This seems also more useful to me, since you definitely will know when you missed to include something, but you might never know if you included stuff you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a declaration of a given `QClass`, you can either explicitly ask for it by including `<QClass>`, or you can implicitly get it by including the `<QtModule>` the class is in. So, you only ever need to include `<QClass>`, but can do it indirectly via including `<QtModule>` to save yourself from having to include dozens of `<QClass>`es directly.

The `<QtModule>` include pulls in all of the headers for the types declared by a given module, and also includes the modules it depends on. For example, `<QtWidgets>` will pull `<QtGui>`, `<QWidget>`, etc. Then, `<QtGui>` pulls `<QtCore>`, `<QPainter>`, etc.

If your project uses only the core, gui and widgets modules, then, at a minimum, every file needs to only `#include <QtWidgets>`, and your own headers as needed, and that takes care of including all of the widgets, gui and core modules.

Given modern preprocessed header systems, it's perfectly fine to e.g. `#include <QtWidgets>` in a header that declares a class that derives from `QWidget`. It'll save you the drudgery of having to list potentially dozens of headers. It won't slow down compilation (measure it to make sure!) - but make sure that you have configured your project to use preprocessed headers.

On the other hand, if you're not using preprocessed headers, your compile times will suffer from each unnecessary header that you include. It's really your call. If you have a small project - less than a 100 source files - it probably won't save you much time if you include entire modules as needed. It's much less typing.

You never need to include `<Qt>`, unless it's the only Qt header you include. The `<Qt>` header declares the members of the `Qt` namespace, e.g. `Qt::GlobalColor` and thus `Qt::red`, etc. You'd typically need to include it if you wish to use an enum from the `Qt` namespace, but don't care for any other Qt functionality. That's a rare need, I'd imagine.

Comment: Allthough this raises the question about preprocessed headers that accurately answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

include definitions of classes only if you use them either for subclassing, or for instantiation by value. For example: you don't need whole `<QtGui>` if you want to subclass from `QWidget`; include `<QWidget>` instead.

Comment: This advice is too general to be usable. There are cases where it's perfectly acceptable to include entire modules. I have 100+ file projects that include entire modules only, since the builds exclusively use preprocessed headers and the compile time impact is <5% over the minimal include set.

Comment: @KubaOber, after you compile whole big module (like QtGui in particular) once, there is almost no impact. But you never have to compile full QtGui module because you never use all classes from it. If you never use big includes at all, the impact can be drastic for small projects.

Comment: All of the recent examples I post here (and on // https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/) use whole-module includes for brevity and I see no impact... and I don't even use precompiled headers. The compilation takes <5s in any case, usually 1-2s.

Comment: To give an idea of the impact, on a modern laptop (2015 Asus ROG), with warm caches and a mechanical hard drive, under VS2015, the compilation of a file with nothing but `#include <QtModule>` for **all** Qt modules, an empty `main`, and no other code, takes <10s, with no precompiled headers in use.